# how to convert a pandas dataframe to a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,2,2,2,3],
        'value': ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value'])
```

I want to convert it to a list of dictionary like:

```
df_dict = [
{
 'id': 1,
 'value':['a','b']
},
{
'id': 2,
'value':['c','d','e']
},
{
'id': 3,
'value':['f']
}
]
```

And then eventually insert this list `df_dict` to another dictionary:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "productID": 1234,
            "tag": df_dict
        }
  ]
}
```

We don't need to worry about how the other dictionary looks like. We can simply use the example I gave above.

How do I do that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby and then use [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert it to a dictionary.

```
>>> df.groupby(df['id'], as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict(orient="records")
[{'id': 1, 'value': ['a', 'b']}, {'id': 2, 'value': ['c', 'd', 'e']}, {'id': 3, 'value': ['f']}]
```